# Adjusting the size of a background sprite image on a List Item

Tags: html, css, html-lists

http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/Mt87G/1/

I am trying to do an un-ordered list, each list item will

- have a background sprite image, with text to the right of it
- have a different image when hovered over
- show the hover image if the class "active" exist - see my second list item for demo
- If the list row is wrapped in  tags, then it will link the text and the image together as one, so you hover over text or image and they both make the background image change

  - each row will have a top border

If you view my jsfiddle page above, you will see I have it how I describe, except there are some problems

- My background image is not letting me set dimensions, or they appear not to work
- my background image is showing through, where the text stretches over

If I can resolve these 2 issues, I think I will be in  good shape.

----- A couple of notes about the code, there are many padding, margins, etc.. that are 0, I left them in there like that for easy testing/changing for now until the code is done.  Also I have the same class name and background image for all the items, that will change into seperate images, once I figure it out with the one it should be no problem.

Please help me if you can, I am stumped, thank you

```
<ul id="post-meta-wrapper">
    <li class="author">
        <a href="#"><span class="meta-img">Test link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="author">
        <a href="#"><span class="active meta-img">Test link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="author">
        <a href="#"><span class="meta-img">Test link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="author">
        <a href="#"><span class="meta-img">Test link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="author">
        <a href="#"><span class="meta-img">Test link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="author">
        <a href="#"><span class="meta-img">Test link</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

css

```
#post-meta-wrapper{
    list-style: none;
    margin:20px 0 20px 20px;
    width:400px;
}

#post-meta-wrapper li {
    width:100%;
    color: #44495B;
    border-top: 1px dotted #CCC;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-indent: 0px;
}

#post-meta-wrapper .meta-img {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Bcps8.png) no-repeat 0px -183px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 18px;
}

#post-meta-wrapper .meta-img:hover,
#post-meta-wrapper .active{
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Bcps8.png) no-repeat 0px -195px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
#post-meta-wrapper li a{
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Bcps8.png) no-repeat 0px -183px;
    padding-left:15px;
}

#post-meta-wrapper .meta-img {
    background:#fff;
    width: 15px;
    height: 10px;
    padding-left:8px;
}
```

Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Mt87G/2/

Comment: good idea, do you know how to make the width and height work?  Notice how the area shown is larger then the width and height set for the image